# Why isn't my Firebase/Auth package installed in xcode(swift 5)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

This is my pod file and have installed, uninstalled and reinstalled everything 5 times and for some reason it just doesn't work

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PharmaHome Connections' do

## Pods for PharmaHome Connections

```
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

end

Once I install everything this comes up in the terminal:

```
-> Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 18 total pods installed.
```

[!] The `PharmaHome Connections [Debug]` target overrides the `PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-PharmaHome Connections/Pods-PharmaHome Connections.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `PharmaHome Connections [Debug]` target overrides the `PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-PharmaHome Connections/Pods-PharmaHome Connections.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `PharmaHome Connections [Release]` target overrides the `PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-PharmaHome Connections/Pods-PharmaHome Connections.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `PharmaHome Connections [Release]` target overrides the `PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-PharmaHome Connections/Pods-PharmaHome Connections.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

In Xcode I go and change the Release and Debug a both in the

> PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR and MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO

to $(inherited), and it raises an Error

```
/Users/user/Desktop/PharmaHome Connections/PharmaHome Connections/ViewController.swift:11:8: No such module 'FirebaseAuth'
```

If I remove the $(inherited), a different error is raised saying
`Framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement`

Once I do everything again after closing the app this error appears:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMIdentifiers", referenced from:
*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAIdentifiers in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAIdentifiers_073326a72300f5375513acd0fc54f452.o)
"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_APMIdentifiers", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FIRAIdentifiers in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAIdentifiers_073326a72300f5375513acd0fc54f452.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMScreenViewReporter", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAScreenViewReporter_e7c01d781332b9006760b4d7506bf755.o)
*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAScreenViewReporter in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAScreenViewReporter_e7c01d781332b9006760b4d7506bf755.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMAdExposureReporter", referenced from:
*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAAdExposureReporter in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAAdExposureReporter_dca1be02bb82133dc9310c1cb2b2cfe3.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMIdentity", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMSessionReporter", referenced from:
*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRASessionReporter in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASessionReporter_6ccd98dbbd8ab462f7f778c620e15947.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMConditionalUserPropertyController", referenced from:
*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAConditionalUserPropertyController in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAConditionalUserPropertyController_4bda5cb35a89f6c6dd5a502c214436e6.o)
"_APMIsAnalyticsCollectionEnabled", referenced from:
+[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"_APMIsAnalyticsCollectionDeactivated", referenced from:
+[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"_APMMonitorLogTagOptionKey", referenced from:
+[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"_gAPMAppMeasurementLibraryVersion", referenced from:
+[FIRAnalytics initialize] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_APMUserAttribute", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FIRAUserAttribute in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAUserAttribute_cd666440930283221a8f5970e073d6c4.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMAnalytics", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMConditionalUserProperty", referenced from:
*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAConditionalUserProperty in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAConditionalUserProperty_8927b5f8e4b44834d98ab82ca1058ebd.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMEvent", referenced from:
*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAEvent in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAEvent_31e2773e69be479b12b059a54f67a005.o)
"_APMFormattedEventName", referenced from:
+[FIRAnalytics logEventWithOrigin:name:parameters:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_APMConditionalUserPropertyController", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FIRAConditionalUserPropertyController in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAConditionalUserPropertyController_4bda5cb35a89f6c6dd5a502c214436e6.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMUserAttribute", referenced from:
*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAUserAttribute in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAUserAttribute_cd666440930283221a8f5970e073d6c4.o)
"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_APMSessionReporter", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FIRASessionReporter in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRASessionReporter_6ccd98dbbd8ab462f7f778c620e15947.o)
"_APMFormattedUserPropertyName", referenced from:
+[FIRAnalytics setUserPropertyString:forName:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMValue", referenced from:
*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAValue in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAValue_acbb0e0d63888006fda7982f24b7e100.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_APMMeasurement", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_9909b8b273787a3d6303ba22319b9c2d.o)
*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAMeasurement in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_9909b8b273787a3d6303ba22319b9c2d.o)
objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"_APMAnalyticsConfiguration", referenced from:
+[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_APMScreenViewReporter", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FIRAScreenViewReporter in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAScreenViewReporter_e7c01d781332b9006760b4d7506bf755.o)
"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_APMAdExposureReporter", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FIRAAdExposureReporter in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAAdExposureReporter_dca1be02bb82133dc9310c1cb2b2cfe3.o)
"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_APMConditionalUserProperty", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FIRAConditionalUserProperty in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAConditionalUserProperty_8927b5f8e4b44834d98ab82ca1058ebd.o)
"_APMSafelistedEventsOptionKey", referenced from:
+[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_APMMeasurement", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FIRAMeasurement in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAMeasurement_9909b8b273787a3d6303ba22319b9c2d.o)
"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_APMEvent", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FIRAEvent in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAEvent_31e2773e69be479b12b059a54f67a005.o)
"_APMAppMeasurementOriginFirebase", referenced from:
+[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ad263b29c3fc023c44d18b4b635e8d55.o)
"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_APMValue", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FIRAValue in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAValue_acbb0e0d63888006fda7982f24b7e100.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

No matter what I do an error pops up. Yesterday, with the exact same setup, no error was raised! Please someone help me I have already wasted 3 hour trying to solve this problem!

Here are my pods settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue like this:

- Clean Build folder
- Close Xcode
- Run pod install

when installation is finished

- Run pod update

when update is finished

- Open the project

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleaned the build and rebuild again?

In my case, it worked.

Comment: How can I clean it?

Comment: Xcode/Product/Clean Build Folder

Or shortcut key: Window+Shift+K

Comment: I cleaned it but the Firebase/Auth module still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was a bit more complicated!

1. Clean the Build
2. Go to Build Settings > User Defined
3. Change the PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH to the path of the folder in which your project is located. (The $(inherited) shows the path to the Pods not the project.
4. Run 'pod install --verbose' in the terminal
5. Close the application and reopen and you are ready!